# AngularJS - How do I change the State from Inside the Controller

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, state

I am new to AngularJS and would like to know how I change the State from within the Controller.

For example, I typically change the state on a button click:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Log In" ui-sref="main.navigation"/>
```

So on Submit of the button, my page will change to the navigation page. This works fine, but what if I want to do some logic in my controller first, and then based off the results, I would want to change to a specific page. How do I do this from within the controller, versus from a button click.

Here is my modules.js in case you are curious:

```
angular.module('ecsMain', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngTable'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('main/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'view/main.html'
        })
        .state('main.login', {
            url: '',
            controller: ECSMainController,
            templateUrl: 'view/login.html'
        })
        .state('main.phoneCalls', {
            url: '',
            controller: AccordionDemoCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'view/phoneCalls.html'
        })
        .state('main.navigation', {
            url: '',
            controller: ModalDemoCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'view/navigation.html'
        })
        .state('main.myModalContent', {
            url: '',
            controller: ModalDemoCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'view/myModalContent.html'
        })
        .state('main.alertMessage', {
            url: '',
            controller: ModalDemoCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'view/alertMessage.html'
        })
}]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

inject `$state` service to your controller, then in your controller...

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.changeState = function () {
    $state.go('where.ever.you.want.to.go', {stateParamKey: exampleParam});
};
```

and add `ng-click` to your button

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="changeState()">Change State</button>
```

Comment: You're a life saver... worked like a charm! Saved me hours of trying to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Can we also pass params when we change the state here ?