# How to activate default state in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router 0.2.18

Main referral admin URL for my website looks like this http://example.com/partners/dashboard I want it to be changed to http://example.com/partners/dashboard#referral-link (to bootstrap corresponding ui-router's state: `referral-link`). But it seems that `when` method does not work...

**app.js**

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // it does not work...
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/partners/dashboard', '/partners/dashboard#/referral-link');

    var referralLinkState = {
        name: 'referral-link',
        url: '/referral-link',
        template: '<kr-partners-referral-link></kr-partners-referral-link>'
    };

    var myClientsState = {
        name: 'my-clients',
        url: '/my-clients',
        template: '<kr-partners-my-clients></kr-partners-my-clients>'
    };
    // ...
    $stateProvider.state(referralLinkState);
    $stateProvider.state(myClientsState);    
}]);
```

---

**ADDED LATER:** Guys, I think your `.otherwise` method will not work for me. Because it will override all URLs, but I need to override only one specific URL.

Comment: Do you want to add a default route or just a common base path?

Comment: I want to create a redirection only for this url:  http://example.com/partners/dashboard

Comment: this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172749/redirect-state-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Use .otherwise clause with string argument:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/referral-link');
```

Or with callback for dynamic:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
    $state.go(..put state name here);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569209/1056253

Basically what I did - is injected `$state` inside /partners/dashboard `controller` and called its `go` method like so: `$state.go('referral-link');`